# data.table difference set of columns from another column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to difference a set of columns from another column with `data.table`. Here's a simple example:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a=1:10,b=11:20,d=21:30)
mycols <- c("b","d")
dt[,c(paste0("diff",mycols)):=lapply(mycols, function(x, env) get(x,env) - get("a",env), env=dt)]
dt
     a  b  d diffb diffd
 1:  1 11 21    10    20
 2:  2 12 22    10    20
 3:  3 13 23    10    20
 4:  4 14 24    10    20
 5:  5 15 25    10    20
 6:  6 16 26    10    20
 7:  7 17 27    10    20
 8:  8 18 28    10    20
 9:  9 19 29    10    20
10: 10 20 30    10    20
```

My question is whether there is a better syntax for this with `data.table`? The issue is that the column "a" is not defined within the scope of the function, so I have to use get to make it work.

Comment: Your question explains how to use the concept of environment inside a data.table. This further helped me understand data.table. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subset `.SD` using `mycols` and subtract `a`:

```
dt[, paste0("diff", mycols) := .SD[, mycols, with = FALSE] - a ]
#     a  b  d diffb diffd
# 1:  1 11 21    10    20
# 2:  2 12 22    10    20
# 3:  3 13 23    10    20
# 4:  4 14 24    10    20
# 5:  5 15 25    10    20
# 6:  6 16 26    10    20
# 7:  7 17 27    10    20
# 8:  8 18 28    10    20
# 9:  9 19 29    10    20
#10: 10 20 30    10    20
```

As Frank pointed out in the comments, this works, too

```
dt[, paste0("diff", mycols) := .SD - dt$a, .SDcols=mycols]
```

Not sure what's better practice, though.

Comment: That's much cleaner. Thanks!